# Best distance between bed slats?

Tags: bedroom

When using a pocket spring mattress with a pine bed frame, what's the best distance to leave between the pine slats to reduce wear?

Looking online, I have seen various space recommendations ranging from 1cm to 7cm (0.5 inch to 2.5 inches). I notice the smaller recommendations tend to come from older posts, so I am not sure if maybe the correct way of doing this has changed?

Also, I've seen that some gap is needed between the slats to allow ventilation (to prevent the springs over heating), so it's all a bit confusing to pick the right size!

It is for a single bed and the user is around 13st. Would a 3cm gap be enough or is that too wide for support or too narrow for ventilation?

Comment: why would you be concerned about the springs overheating?

Comment: @jsotola I read that if they don't have enough ventilation they get too warm and so over time they will wear out more quickly.